# No me detecta mi CSS en Laravel cuando lo quiero volver a aplicar por segunda vez

Tags: css, laravel

esta es mi vista la cual no me funciona

```
@extends('adminlte::layouts.app')
    @section('htmlheader_title')
    @endsection
    @section('main-content')
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="container-fluid spark-screen">

            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Home</div>

                        <div class="panel-body">


                            {{Form::open(array( 'url'=>'departamento.editar','id'=>'formulario','method'=>'post'))}}


                            <h1>Editar<span class="badge badge-secondary">Empleado</span></h1>


                            <div class="modal-body mx-6">

                                {{--<ul class="nav nav-pills">--}}
                                    {{--<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>--}}
                                    {{--<li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>--}}
                                    {{--<li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>--}}
                                    {{--<li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>--}}
                                {{--</ul>--}}

                     </div>
                   {{Form::close()}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

@endsection
```

esta es mi vista que si me funciona

```
                    <html>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalempleados" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg " role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header text-center">
                <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Empleado</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body mx-6">

                <ul class="tabs">
                    <li><a href="#tab1">Datos Generales</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab2">Datos Laborales</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab3">Datos de la ficha</a></li>
                </ul>
                {{Form::open(array( 'url'=>'#','id'=>'formulario','method'=>'post'))}}
  </div>

            {{Form::close()}}
```

Este es mi CSS

```
ul.tabs {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    height: 32px; /*--Set height of tabs--*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
    width: 100%;
}


ul.tabs li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 31px; /*--Subtract 1px from the height of the unordered list--*/
    line-height: 31px; /*--Vertically aligns the text within the tab--*/
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: none;
    margin-bottom: -1px; /*--Pull the list item down 1px--*/
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background: #e0e0e0;
}
ul.tabs li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border: 1px solid #fff; /*--Gives the bevel look with a 1px white border inside the list item--*/
    outline: none;
}
ul.tabs li a:hover {
    background: #ccc;
}
html ul.tabs li.active, html ul.tabs li.active a:hover  { /*--Makes sure that the active tab does not
        listen to the hover properties--*/
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; /*--Makes the active tab look like it's connected with
        its content--*/
}


.tab_container {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-top: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
    float: left; width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}
.tab_content {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

Comment: Falta mucha información, ¿cómo sabemos qué hay de diferente entre una y otra vista? Con lo que vemos, todo se ve bien.

Comment: es practicamente lo mismo solo que uno esta en un modal y otra normal pero la del modal si me funciona pero ya esta otra no

Comment: Con esa información no podemos ayudar, no es suficiente... si te pones en el lugar de quienes vemos la pregunta, vemos dos códigos iguales...

Comment: si entiendo voy a ver si modifico el codigo par que lo visualicen mejor

Comment: ya lo modifique no se si asi se entiende mejor

Comment: No veo que esté el código en mención en la primera vista.